# Error Generating GraalVM Image: 'dial tcp: lookup' Issue with objects.githubusercontent.com

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm encountering an error while creating an image in GraalVM. However, there's an important point to note: when attempting to create an image by selecting earlier versions of GraalVM, I don't face any issues. However, when I try the newer versions after a certain release, I encounter an error.

"My current system settings."

`
Java Version:

java 21.0.1 2023-10-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Oracle GraalVM 21.0.1+12.1 (build 21.0.1+12-jvmci-23.1-b19, mixed mode, sharing)

Computer:
i7 Cpu , 64Gb Ram, Winows 11

Docker Desktop last version

`

Working example:

```
Build.gradle config

 bootBuildImage {
        builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder:0.1.374-tiny'
        environment = [
                "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS":"-Xmx16384M",
                'BP_NATIVE_IMAGE': 'true'
        ]

    }

Create Docker Image Code:
./gradlew bootBuildImage --imageName=graaldemo
```

"When I specifically mention a version above, the system works fine, but when I try to use newer versions or don't specify a version here, I encounter the following error."

```
 [creator]     Paketo Buildpack for Syft 1.41.1
    [creator]       https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/syft
    [creator]         Downloading from https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.98.0/syft_0.98.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
    [creator]     unable to get dependency syft
    [creator]     unable to download https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.98.0/syft_0.98.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     unable to request https://github.com/anchore/syft/releases/download/v0.98.0/syft_0.98.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz
    [creator]     Get "https://objects.githubusercontent.com/github-production-release-asset-2e65be/262126497/dcc1aed3-87ae-4236-b9c4-fba6fbf785f0?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20231223%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231223T211325Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=597aa2ae5009864df5d67bbaba6d3f1179792
75bd3253d1fa499d9643c4f8b06&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=262126497&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dsyft_0.98.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream": dial tcp: lookup objects.githubusercontent.com: i/o timeout
    [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1

> Task :bootBuildImage FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootBuildImage'.
> Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 51

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

"Is there anyone who can help me solve this issue?"

"I've tried using different Java versions to resolve the issue, experimented with various updated GraalVM versions, changed the language of the operating system, disabled the antivirus program, but none of these worked."